# How to do this query condition in cakephp?

Tags: sql, cakephp, join

How can I make this query the CakePHP way?

```
SELECT *
FROM uploaded_sales us, sales s
WHERE us.item_id = s.audience_id
```

The column `item_id` of `uploaded_sales` table is not its primary key.

The column `audience_id` of `sales` table is not its primary key too.

I tried this one on my model, I'm not getting any errors but it still returns `sales` as empty:

```
$reports = $this->find('all',
  array(
    'joins' => array(
      array(
        'table' => 'sales',
        'alias' => 'Sale',
        'type' => 'left',
        'conditions' => array('Sale.audience_id' => 'UploadedSale.item_id')
    )),
    'conditions' => array(
      'UploadedSale.month' => $month,
      'UploadedSale.year' => $year,
      'UploadedSale.company_id' => $company_id,
      'UploadedSale.item_type' => $item_type
    ),
    'fields' => $fields
));

return $reports;
```

Comment: It always strikes me, how much easier is it to write a real SQL statement, which, if you are using joins, is actually orders of magnitude faster, then one generated by ORM ...

Comment: @tereško Problem is ORM are not targeted at SQL gurus and a good ORM can protect you against a couple of malicious attacks. However, they used to have methods to implement raw SQL queries. In fact, CakePHP has a pretty `query()` method.

Comment: @elitalon , so the benefit of ORMs is that they protect you from learning?

Comment: @tereško No. They protect you from not applying good programming practices such reusability, decoupling, etc. They intend to cover the most used tasks while providing alternatives when you want to go a step beyond. It's up to the developer to do it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about using the Containable behavior in CakePHP:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

It will make joins a helluva lot easier.